# Receiving millions of errors in Google Webmaster

Tags: robots.txt

I in the search section of Google and in the following prices
**Blocked by robots.txt**
and also
**Page with redirect**
I get 2,500,000 errors
([This is my robots.txt file](https://getandroid.ir/robots.txt))

Most errors start with the following pattern:
https://getandroid.ir/go.php?url=/

for example:
`https://getandroid.ir/go.php?url=http%3A%2F%2F66ZdfPSO05h.sucdutedu.org/ZdfPSO05h/ https://getandroid.ir/go.php?url=http%3A%2F%2F669yEgtvaOt.terronponce.org/9yEgtvaOt/ https://getandroid.ir/go.php?url=http%3A%2F%2F66AstjPLBru.skachay.site/AstjPLBru/`

The go.php file is empty and has nothing inside

Also, I use the following code for redirect in .htaccess

> RewriteEngine On Redirect 301 /go.php
> https://www.google.com/search?q=get+android Redirect 301 /go.php
> /404.php ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Please help me, best regards

I use the following code for redirect in .htaccess
`RewriteEngine On Redirect 301 /go.php https://www.google.com/search?q=get+android Redirect 301 /go.php /404.php ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`